# Drawing a window not working, icon shows on task bar but not on screen

Tags: visual-c++

Wrote a simple program that should display an empty window but its not drawing it on screen, the icon show up on the task manager and it uses cpu power to keep it up but its not showing on the screen, Anyone know a fix or know what i have done wrong?

Here is my code:

```c
#include<Windows.h>
#include<d2d1.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY)
        {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
                DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPWSTR cmd, int nCmdShow)
{
        WNDCLASSEX windowclass;
        ZeroMemory(&windowclass, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

        windowclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        windowclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
        windowclass.hInstance = hinstance;
        windowclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
        windowclass.lpszClassName = "CrystalWindow";
        windowclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

        RegisterClassEx(&windowclass);

        HWND windowHandle = CreateWindow("CrystalWindow", "Crystal Engine", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,100, 100, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hinstance, 0);

        if (!windowHandle)
        {
                return -1;
        }

        ShowWindow(windowHandle,nCmdShow);

        MSG message;
        while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
                DispatchMessage(&message);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the `DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);` call in your `WindowProc`, such that it is *never* called. Move it to *outside* the `if` block:

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // Call default first!
    if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    //  DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // Here, it is never called!
    }
    return result; // Return the result from the DefWindowProc call!
}
```

Comment: thanks you saved me.. this is my final major project at college, thanks again life saver.

Comment: Always happy to help, @Mateusz - that's what Stack Overflow is for! Feel to [explore how SO works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you found it useful.‎